# Pandas left Merge not working on two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, where the first dataframa is about the usage by the id and the date, and the second is all dates from 2020-01 to 2022-12

```
df_usage = 
id           date   
1            2020-01  
1            2020-02  
2            2020-01
...          ...
51999999962  2022-05


df_dates =
date
2020-01
2020-02
2020-03
2020-04
.
.
2022-12
```

i do the following merge, because i want a unique dataframe with all id's and dates, with indicator if the user has an usage or not in that month:

```
df_merged = df_dates.merge(df_usage, how='left', on='date', indicator=True)
```

and i got the following df, with all rows with both indicator:

```
        date    id              _merge
0   2020-10 123456789   both
1   2022-09 51900000051 both
2   2022-10 51900000051 both
3   2022-11 51900000260 both
4   2022-12 51900001148 both
... ... ... ...
1752211 2021-07 51999999962 both
1752212 2021-08 51999999962 both
1752213 2021-09 51999999962 both
1752214 2021-10 51999999962 both
1752215 2021-11 51999999962 both
```

and when i select a single row by id with loc

```
df_merged.loc[df_merged['id']=='123456789']
```

i get the following:

```
0   2020-10 123456789   both
```

a single row,
but i want this:

```
        date    id              _merge
0   2020-10 123456789   both
1   2020-11 123456789   left-only
2   2020-12 123456789   left-only
...     ...     ...             ...
x   2022-12 123456789   left-only
```

because i do the left merge by the df_dates dataframe

How can i solve this?

Expected output:

```
0   2020-10 123456789   both
1   2020-11 123456789   left-only
2   2020-12 123456789   left-only
...     ...     ...             ...
26  2022-12 123456789   left-only
27  2022-09 51900000051 both
28  2022-10 51900000051 both
29  2022-11 51900000051 both
30  2022-12 51900000051 left-only
... ... ... ...
1752211 2022-12 51999999962 left-only
```

Comment: "Left" refers to the dataframe on which `merge` method was called (`df_dates`). Try "right" or switch places with `df_usage`.

Comment: i got the same result :(